# How do I graph the change in a spreadsheet with 3 values over time?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So let's say I want to track the total items sold at different stores over the year. (This is an example for privacy reasons)

Something like: April 2023:

| Store A | Store B |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1: (6) | Item 1 (8) |
| Item 2: (20) | Item 2 (13) |

May 2023:

| Store A | Store B |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1: (14) | Item 1 (19) |
| Item 2: (35) | Item 2 (34) |

Is there a way to insert a slider or something to display this information on a single sheet? If Google sheets can't do this is there a program that can?

My current solution is to copy the graph and have different sheets for each month. This works, but it would be easier to have the data on a single sheet.

Comment: Use `VSTACK()` formula to consolidate all data from different sheets to a single sheet.

Comment: @Harun24hr A good suggestion but how do you propose to identify the month that any given row relates to.

Comment: `Regarding the dates of the months` Are dates included anywhere in the respective sheets? `Is there a way to insert a slider or something to display this information on a single sheet?` Please provide an example of how you expect a successful outcome would be displayed.